# Can't import openzeppelin node_modules: File import callback not supported

Tags: node.js, solidity, openzeppelin

Whenever I try to compile my solidity contract, the error `ParserError: Source \"@OpenZeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol\" not found: File import callback not supported` gets thrown.

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "@OpenZeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@OpenZeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: are you using VSCode plugin to compile it?

Comment: See my solidity `node_module` referencing here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68459731/8534426

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File import callback not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321111/file-import-callback-not-supported)

Comment: If you read the VS Code extension docs (I am using the extension by Juan Blanco), it has a section about openzepplin. You need to edit your settings and add the following (assuming node_modules is in the root dir of your ptoject) : "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": "",
  "solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesDirectory": "node_modules"

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you opened VS Code in the **root directory of the project**.

In my case, this is how my VS Code directory looked like when I get that same error.

```
projects
 |___MyContract
   |__contracts
     |__Contract.sol
```

Reopening VS Code in the `MyContract` directory fixes it.

```
MyContract
 |__contracts
   |__Contract.sol
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, was using a project cloned from github.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem right now. I'm using truffle+node and I fixed it modifying the import path to a relative path, for example,

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "../node_modules/OpenZeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "../node_modules/OpenZeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

I'm not 100% sure why this happen but I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 8):

After installing OpenZeppelin close your IDE and re-open it.

Comment: You're right, hahaha. The Solidity plugin for VSCode is to blame, I suppose. I edit: the  annoying error didn't go away.

Comment: @Jose4Linux make sure the import path is correct

Answer (score 2):

For some environments, SafeMath has a different path

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me;
(I am using Windows10 and visual studio code)
-click on the extensions icon
-search for the solidity extension
-select the uninstall button and click on the drop down arrow
-select install another version
-select version 0.0.135
-After the installation, click on "Reload required"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had a similar bug with version 0.0.163 installed and switching to a previous version fixed the issue(I switched to v0.0.153).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed openzeppelin

```
npm install --save @openzeppelin/contracts@v3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

actualy the problem is solidity compiler is stupid and doesn't automatically follow path, you have to specify all allowed path manually (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/using-the-compiler.html), every each one of them and completely to the file(cannot give juste the higher level folder) use npx hardat compile if you can it's better

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

Change the settings in Solidity extension in VSCode.

*The default settings include:
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": "contracts"
Users need to change the setting from contracts to an empty string.
"solidity.packageDefaultDependenciesContractsDirectory": ""*

Source - https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity/issues/178

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import "{Project Name}/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```