# remapping or Parse error_is this fixable in my environment? Importing open zeppelin contracts fails

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, solidity

When I set import to "@openzeppelin/contracts/etc/etc" VS Code immediately shows **not found. File import call back not supported** but running truffle compile shows what I think looks better (considering the output).
When I change the import to "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/etc/etc" VS code likes it but truffle compile output now A) shows WAY more contracts, B) hits me with errors like "this function; this var; has already been delcared". It shows the error in live in my files and points to the relevant imported source contract as the first to declare. I can't get truffle solc-js compiler to understand that these are separate contracts and it is a reference... It's like both the imported and my contracts are in the same folder or something. (but are not).

I have changed the names of literally everything (I think) except for my CrowSale sol file name. I just can't figure out which combination of attempts is the right one or maybe it is a config setting and not a naming or syntax issue.

#### Questions

Why are the contents of imported contracts like ERC20.sol creating a declaration error based on the contents of my contracts. Where are/is my error(s) in the A) File Name B) import call C) contract declaration D) or in deployment artifacts require(a file) naming scheme?

#### my environment

```
Truffle v5.5.0 (core: 5.5.0)
Ganache v7.0.1
Solidity - ^0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v14.9.0
Web3.js v1.5.3
```

[VsCode Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHUfz.png)

#### CrowdSale sol "mine"

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <6.0;

import "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "./myToken.sol";

contract CrowdSale{
    address payable admin;
    myToken public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    constructor (myToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }
```

#### myToken sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <6.0;

import "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract myToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    string public name = "myToken";
    string public symbol = "myToken";
    uint256 public totalSupply; //removed = _amount;state variables

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbols,
        unit8 _decimals,
        unit256 _amount
    ) public ERC20Detailed(_name, _symbols, _decimals) {
        _mint(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
```

#### 2 deploy contracts js

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
var myToken = artifacts.require("./myToken.sol");
var CrowdSale = artifacts.require("./CrowdSale.sol");

  module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(myToken, 100001).then(function() {
      var tokenPrice = 17000000000000000000;
      return deployer.deploy(CrowdSale, myToken.address, tokenPrice);
    });
   };
```

##Edited / added

```
 Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/PreSale.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/tFief.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/GSN/Context.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol

project:/contracts/tFief.sol:13:1: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
contract ERC20Detailed {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/tFief.sol:10:1: The previous declaration is here:
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol';
^-------------------------------------------------------------^
,project:/contracts/tFief.sol:23:1: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
contract ERC20 is ERC20Detailed {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/tFief.sol:11:1: The previous declaration is here:
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';
```

Comment: I spent last 2 days focused on abstracts and interfaces; learning function + method overloading a multilevel inheritance (polymorphic ?). I was I am closer but still getting two compilation errors (better than 30). I will put the error message/code in my question above and mark it **edit**

Comment: Your code does not show how you compile.  I got the error `File import call back not supported ` when I did not use an import callback as explained on the GitHub page of the solc compiler at https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js .  I explained how I solved the error in my case at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321111/file-import-callback-not-supported/72241149#72241149